# Increase chunk size limit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is there some config file that increases the storage limit of a specific chunk up from what it is now?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such option. And chunks that go above the storage limit already automatically reset, so there is very likely no way to restore whatever was in there.

Comment: What is a "Chunk Storage Limit?"  I can't find a definition for the term.

Comment: I'm wondering a bit why you're reading this question if you don't even have that problem, but OK… :D Minecraft saves the world split into 16×256×16 areas called "chunks". They hold all the data for that area, including blocks, entities and more. The data gets compressed before they get written to a file, but under some rare circumstances (usually encountered only in Creative or when doing this intentionally), the size of the compressed data can be above a certain limit. For some reason (probably to prevent arbitrarily big save files from filling the hard drive), Minecraft then doesn't save …

Comment: … the chunk at all then and instead deletes it, which causes it to get regenerated when it's loaded the next time.

Comment: Intellectual inquisitiveness.

Comment: @Fabian chunks aren't deleted and regenerated when they're not able to save, AFAIK, they're just rolled back to the last saved version, which allows for item duplication.